# Add string as an attribute in element from xml value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

The below xml input which contains the styles and those content should be appended with  element as mentioned below in xslt 1.0.

Input XML:

```
<component>
          <content>Sponsored by abc.</content>
          <tableCellAttributes> rowspan="1" style="FONT-WEIGHT:UNDERLINE; width:576px;background:rgb(200,201,202);"
          </tableCellAttributes>  
</component>
```

Required Output:

```
  <tr>
           <td rowspan="1" style="FONT-WEIGHT:UNDERLINE; width:576px;background:rgb(200,201,202);">Sponsored by abc™. </td> 
  </tr>
```

Comment: I think you could get some info by asking on XML related sites, or googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212489/how-to-set-attribute-in-xml-using-xslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <tr>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
            td <xsl:value-of select="component/tableCellAttributes"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="component/content"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
            /td<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is pretty ugly, and runs a risk of outputting illegal (X)HTML.

You might be better off modifying your Schema so your input XML looks more like this:

```
<component>
          <content>Sponsored by abc.</content>
          <tableCellAttributes>
              <attribute>
                  <name>rowspan</name>
                  <value>1</value>
              </attribute>
              <attribute>
                  <name>style</name>
                  <value>FONT-WEIGHT:UNDERLINE; width:576px;background:rgb(200,201,202);</value>
              </attribute>
          </tableCellAttributes>  
</component>
```

Then you can use a cleaner XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:for-each select="component/tableCellAttributes/attribute">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name}"><xsl:value-of select="value"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="component/content"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. We have implemented the same logic in our XSLT. But we didn't do any change in the schema design.